Voting for comments from the review queues doesn't work
If you click on the up arrow next to a comment from the review queue, the page scrolls and the voting doesn't work (printscreen is from Stack Overflow in Russian, but I think, the language isn't important):

At this time, the following error appears in the browser console:
review-v2-transpiled.ru.js?v=25b3dff85b3a:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'reviewTaskId')
    at review-v2-transpiled.ru.js?v=25b3dff85b3a:1:37485

Originally published on Stack Overflow in Russian Meta: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/14248.

Does this answer your question? Allow voting on comments from Review interface While you may be getting an error in your console, I am pretty sure this has never been a working feature, or a feature at all.

@Timothy no it is not a duplicate, as the answer there says "This is now status-completed (though I'm not sure when it has been implemented exactly); it's possible to upvote (and flag) comments in all review queues" and that's not true in the case here. If it was still open then it could still be duplicate of course, but it's closed. So better leave this report open so a developer has a chance to take a look.

Please check if you get same errors as those here, if you do, it's a duplicate, let me know.

Feels like it's more than this. I've had issues adding or deleting comments too.

The UI for the First Questions queue was broken like this this morning, it has been for some time for me. Perhaps because I use Firefox?

The error message from the post Shadow mentions is also an Uncaught TypeError, "t.state is null". "Cannot read properties of null" sounds like it could imply the same. Maybe the review-v2-transpiled.ru.js script is slightly different from the review-v2-transpiled.en.js script?

I perform quite a bit of reviewing on SE, and I have noticed this issue as well.  If memory serves correctly, this was working correctly (after it was implemented) until somewhat recently (perhaps 2-3 months ago?), and then stopped working consistently.  Hopefully it can be fixed.
